# Removing particular array element from array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to remove a choosen element from array, when clicking on delete in my code,
but I can't achive the goal so far.
I was trying to compare current array value with tag value and if they equal,
remove that value from array
I think I'm missing something during processs
Need sum guiding))))thanks
here is my js code

```
$(function(){
var tableHead =
    "<table>" +
        "<tr>" +
            "<th class='sort'>Id sort</th>" +
            "<th>Name</th>" +
            "<th>Surname</th>" +
            "<th>Birthday</th>" +
            "<th>Filter</th>" +
            "<th class='addList'>+</th>" +
        "</tr>" +
    "</table>";

$('body').html(tableHead);

var name = "<input type='text' class='name' placeholder='First name'>";
var surname = "<input type='text' class='surname' placeholder='Surname'>";
var bDayDate ="<input type='date' class='bDayDate' placeholder='Bday'>";
var addList = $('.addList');
var idNum = 0;
var arrNum= [];
var sortedArr = [];

addList.on("click", function(){
    idNum++;
   var tr = $("<tr></tr>");
    for(var i = 1; i <= 6; i++){
        var td = $('<td></td>');
        tr.addClass(""+ idNum);
        switch (i){
            case 1:
                td.addClass(""+ idNum);
                td.html(idNum);
            break;
            case 2: td.html(name);
            break;
            case 3: td.html(surname);
            break;
            case 4: td.html(bDayDate);
            break;
            case 5: td.html(1);
            break;
            case 6:
                td.html("Delete");
                td.addClass('delete');
            break;
            default:
                return console.log("OooPs!!");
        }
        tr.append(td);
    }

    var value;
    arrNum.push(tr);
    $('table').append(arrNum);

    arrNum.forEach(function(val,i){
        value = val
    });

    $('.delete').on("click", function(){
       $(this).parent().remove();
       var that = $(this).parent();
        for(var k = 0;k <arrNum.length - 1; k++){
            if(that[k] === value[k]){
                arrNum.splice(k,1)
            } else {
                console.log("wrong!!")
            }
        }

    });

    for(var j = arrNum.length; j >= 0; j--){
        sortedArr.push(arrNum[j]);
    }

    $(".sort").on("click", function(){
        $('table').append(sortedArr);
        $('.delete').on("click", function(){
            $(this).parent().remove();

        });
    });
});
```

});

Comment: So what have you tried and what results did you get?

Comment: i tried to compare my array index on $(.'delete') parent number
tried to compare array value with $(.'delete') parent value to remove that array element
probably doing something wrong

i need to do that, because when I'm deleting <tr> tag i need also to delete that array element, so when sorting, the deleted elements didn't apppear again

Comment: I actually mean that you should update your question to include what you tried (not an English description of what you tried, but the actual code that you tried) along with what the results were (errors?).

Comment: I updated code
Hope It can help you)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this changes, call this function in your delete events

```
function removeItem(item, arr, sArr)
{
   var that = $(item).parent();
   $(item).parent().remove();

    for(var k = 0;k <arr.length; k++)
    {
       if(arr[k] && that[0] === arr[k][0])
       {
         arr.splice(k,1);
       } else {
         console.log("wrong!!")
       }
    }

    // If you want delete when sort the table
    for(var k = 0;k <sArr.length; k++)
    {
       if(sArr[k] && that[0] === sArr[k][0])
       {
         sArr.splice(k,1);
       } else {
         console.log("wrong!!")
       }
    }
}
```

And call:

```
$('.delete').on("click", function()
{
    removeItem(this, arrNum, sortedArr);
});
```

Comment: strange, it is working
but also returning wrong!! in console

Comment: return wrong!! when the item in the array is different that you want delete

Comment: i don't get it
that means each time when I'm deleting item, it's not that item? 0_o

Comment: you are looping the array and you ask if the current item is equals to the item that you want  delete, but if it dont be show console message. you should delete the else clause

Answer (score 0):

You can use [grep](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/)

```
 arrNum=  $.grep(arrNum, function(e) {

            return e != value ;
        });
```